# Two types of iterators

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

I apologize for all the code but I had a hard time describing what I was trying to do. I am creating a 2D grid for a tile map. The tiles (blocks) are broken up into say a 10x10 square of tiles called a chunk, the chunks form 10x10 squares to form regions, a 10x10 square of regions forms a world. The square side dimension is blockSize.

All coordinates are [X,Y], 0,0 is upper left, all scanning left to right and then top to down.

From Largest to Smallest: World -> Region -> Chunk -> Block.

This image shows how a World with a 2x2 Blocksize would be laid out:

[image]

The "Large" addresses show what each blocks address would be if it were in a single giant array instead of broken up into subunits.

At the end of this post I give a cliff notes version of the code I already have working. I can create all the structures. I have iterators set up (see code at end) so that each level can iterate only the level lower than it. My code can do the following:

```
// Create a world of 10x10 regions, each made up of 10x10 chunks, each made up of 10x10 tiles
World world = new World(blockSize);

// Address the upper left hand corner of the world. The first region's first chunk's first block.
Block block = World.Regions[0,0].Chunks[0,0].Blocks[0,0];

// Address a random chunk
Chunk chunk = World.Regions[1,2].Chunks[6,2];

// Iterate over the Block[,] grid of the given chunk from left to right, up to down
// This will give us every block in Region 1,2 Chunk 6,2
foreach (Block block in chunk) {}

// Address a random region
Region region = World.Regions[4,5];

// Iterate over the Chunk[,] grid of the given region from left to right, up to down
// This will give us every Chunk in Region 4,5
foreach (Chunk chunk in region) {}

// In World, iterate over the Region[,] grid from left to right, up to down
// This will give us every Region in the World
foreach (Region region in World.regions) {}
```

...

What I want is for my iterators to be able to iterate across two levels of my data. For example, given a Region, scan over all the chunks in that region and give me a list of all blocks in the whole thing. Or given a world, get all the chunks in the world. Or an enormous list of all the blocks in the entire World.

...

```
// Given a region, return all chunks in that region
foreach (Chunk chunk in region) {}

// Given a region, return all blocks in all chunks in that region
foreach (Block block in region.GetAllBlocks)
{
    // Scan the chunks from left to right.
    // In each chunk, scan the blocks from left to right.
    // Cover every block in the region.
}

// Given a world, return all the regions
Region regionArray = World.region;     // For clarity
foreach (Region region in regionArray ) {}

// Given a world, return all the chunks in all the regions
Region regionArray = World.region;     // For clarity
foreach (Chunk chunk in regionArray.GetAllChunks)
{
   // Scan the regions from left to right, up to down.
   // In each region, scan the chunks from left to right, up to down.
}

// Given a world, return all the blocks in all the chunks in all the regions
Region regionArray = World.region;     // For clarity
foreach (Block block in regionArray.GetAllBlocks)
{
   // Scan the regions from left to right, up to down.
   // In each region, scan the chunks from left to right, up to down.
   // In each chunk, scan the blocks from left to right, up to down.
}
```

...

How do I write my iterator code so I generate the lists I want? This is the first time I've done anything complex with iterators and I'm having a lot of trouble with figuring out how to do it. Is trying this sort of thing a good idea? Is it efficient/inefficient?

Here is a trimmed down version of what my code looks like to show what I have working:

```
/* **************************************** */
class Block
{
   int blockX, blockY;           // Grid X/Y of this block in it's chunk
   public Block(blockX, blockY)
   {
      this.blockX = blockX;
      this.blockY = blockY;
   }
} // Block Class



/* **************************************** */
class Chunk : IEnumerator, IENumerable
{
    int chunkX, chunkY;       // X/Y of the chunk in it's region
    int blockSize;
    int containsBlocks;
    public Block[,] blocks;
    int enumeratorIndex = -1;

    public Chunk(int chunkX, int chunkY, int blockSize)
    {
        this.chunkX = chunkX;
        this.chunkY = chunkY;
        this.blockSize = blockSize;
        this.containsBlocks = blockSize * blockSize;

        blocks = new Block[blockSize, blockSize];

        for (int x = 0; x < blockSize; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < blockSize; ++y)
            {
                blocks[x, y] = new Block(x, y);
            }
        }
    } // constructor

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        enumeratorIndex++;
        return (enumeratorIndex < this.containsBlocks);
    }

    public void Reset() { enumeratorIndex = 0; }

    public object Current
    {
        get 
        {
            int y = enumeratorIndex / blockSize;
            int x = enumeratorIndex % blockSize;
            return blocks[x, y];
        }
    }
} // Chunk Class



/* **************************************** */
class Region : IEnumerator, IENumerable
{
   int regionX, int regionY;     // X/Y of region in the world
   int blockSize;
   int containsBlocks;
   public Chunks[,] chunks;
   int enumeratorIndex = -1;

   ...
   Same kind of constructor to setup the Chunks[,] array, but this time the iterator is
   ...

    public object Current
    {
        get 
        {
            int y = enumeratorIndex / blockSize;
            int x = enumeratorIndex % blockSize;
            return Chunks[x, y];
        }
    }
} // Region Class


/* **************************************** */
class World : IEnumerator, IENumerable
{
    public Region[,] regions;       // There is only one world, here are it's regions
    int blockSize;

    ...
    etc
    ...

    public object Current
    {
        get 
        {
            int y = enumeratorIndex / blockSize;
            int x = enumeratorIndex % blockSize;
            return Region[x, y];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First suggested change: use the *generic* iterator types... and ideally implement them using *iterator blocks*.

Comment: Once you've implemented `IEnumerable<T>` as Jon suggested, look at the `SelectMany` method: `regions.SelectMany(r => r.Chunks).SelectMany(c => c.Blocks)` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx

Comment: Thanks to both, I think this is exactly what I needed! I will read and add to my project.